# Forks to be aware of other than Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold?

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-gold

I have now taken care of the Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold that I was given "for free" when the hard forks took place, and sent them to other wallets.

Before getting rid of [*] my old Electrum wallet containing all the relevant keys and wallet seed, I wanted to ask the question:

> Are there forks other than Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold I should be aware of that might carry some value?

I guess I can safely assume that SegWit2x will never happen, at least not at the block that was originally planned?

[*] Not exactly getting rid of it, but just take comfort in the fact that I can calmly forget the password, erase that wallet file by mistake etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Current forks that I successfully sold on exchanges and got free BTC:

- Bitcoin Cash
- Bitcoin Gold
- Super Bitcoin
- Bitcore
- Bitcoin Diamond

A few more forks that I wasn't able to sell yet:

- Segwit2x
- Lightning Bitcoin
- United Bitcoin
- Bitcoin God

Answer (score 1):

I've written an article about exactly this here:

https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/wallet-tutorial-add-withdraw-funds/altcoins.php

The article also covers how to easily sweep all of these from your old paper wallet using a single app, and how to convert from one to another.

The coins of significance (right now anyway) are **bitcoin, bitcoin cash, bitcoin gold, and clam coin**. (Yes you read that right, clams.)

Answer (score -1):

There have been a few other forks besides the two you mentioned. BitcoinRed, for example. We just know gold and cash because they are recent and BTC is hot news right now, which is exactly the reason they have increased in value.

If you keep an eye on forums like this you are likely to become aware of potential upcoming forks well before they are scheduled to occur. I know the end goal for the guys over at ViaBTC is to launch Via-bitcoin, and their founders and values seem pretty solid.

Comment: Statements like "their founders and values seem pretty solid" are subjective opinion, and should likely not be part of an answer, unless those statements can be backed up with specific facts.

Comment: Thank you for that. You are so right, and as I search for who these people are, I am regretting not having taken note of it when I first saw the members.